# How to remove fields from insert or updates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql, editing, null

In QGIS 3.22 using a Microsoft SQL Server database I would like inserts or updates to ignore several columns.  The reason being that some columns have values generated by the database.  Currently when I try to insert a feature into a layer QGIS is trying to insert "NULL" into a column - but - I would like the insert statement sent to the database to ignore the column altogethor instead of sending an explicit NULL value.  Some of the QGIS version 2.x releases did not have this problem.

Is it possible to change the behavior of QGIS from inserting explict NULL values, or otherwise, is it possible to remove columns from insert/update functions?

Comment: I noticed that QGIS puts "Autogenerate" in fields that have a identity specification.  Is it possible to tell QGIS to use "Autogenerate" for specific fields?

Comment: What does your insert statement look like?